# Converting milliseconds to a date (jQuery/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I'm a bit of a rambler, but I'll try to keep this clear -

I'm bored, so I'm working on a **"shoutbox"**, and I'm a little confused over one thing. I want to get the time that a message is entered, and I want to make sure I'm getting the server time, or at least make sure I'm not getting the local time of the user. I know it doesn't matter, since this thing won't be used by anyone besides me, but I want to be thorough. I've looked around and tested a few things, and I think the only way to do this is to get the milliseconds since **January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC**, since that'd be the same for everyone.

I'm doing that like so:

```
var time = new Date();
var time = time.getTime();
```

That returns a number like `1294862756114`.

Is there a way to convert `1294862756114` to a more readable date, like `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS`?

So, basically, I'm looking for JavaScript's equivalent of PHP's `date()` function.

Comment: if you don't want to have local time, then why you use javascript for it? shouldn't you do it at server?

Comment: Check this library out -> http://www.datejs.com/ (Check out toString())

Comment: @fazo - This was more or less a project intended to help me get better with JS, so I'm trying to use PHP as little as possible (hopefully only to read/write data to a file).

Comment: I think he meant that he wants to format the time string accordingly?

Comment: `?/?/1970 or whatever it is` -> [Unix Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_Epoch), `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`

Comment: @fazo No, you shouldn't to the calculation on the server. Why burn cycles on the server when the client machine can do them, deliver them faster, and cost less.

Answer (score 388, accepted):

```js
var time = new Date().getTime(); // get your number
var date = new Date(time); // create Date object

console.log(date.toString()); // result: Wed Jan 12 2011 12:42:46 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

Comment: The OP was about converting from a number of milliseconds to a `Date` object, which is what the second line does. The first line is just a way of getting a sensible number of milliseconds. You could also just do `var date = new Date(0);`.

Comment: The time has to be a Number, not String

Answer (score 170):

If you want custom formatting for your date I offer [a simple function](http://phrogz.net/JS/FormatDateTime_JS.txt) for it:

```
var now = new Date;
console.log( now.customFormat( "#DD#/#MM#/#YYYY# #hh#:#mm#:#ss#" ) );
```

Here are the tokens supported:

```
token:     description:             example:
#YYYY#     4-digit year             1999
#YY#       2-digit year             99
#MMMM#     full month name          February
#MMM#      3-letter month name      Feb
#MM#       2-digit month number     02
#M#        month number             2
#DDDD#     full weekday name        Wednesday
#DDD#      3-letter weekday name    Wed
#DD#       2-digit day number       09
#D#        day number               9
#th#       day ordinal suffix       nd
#hhhh#     2-digit 24-based hour    17
#hhh#      military/24-based hour   17
#hh#       2-digit hour             05
#h#        hour                     5
#mm#       2-digit minute           07
#m#        minute                   7
#ss#       2-digit second           09
#s#        second                   9
#ampm#     "am" or "pm"             pm
#AMPM#     "AM" or "PM"             PM
```

And here's the code:

```
//*** This code is copyright 2002-2016 by Gavin Kistner, !@phrogz.net
//*** It is covered under the license viewable at http://phrogz.net/JS/_ReuseLicense.txt
Date.prototype.customFormat = function(formatString){
  var YYYY,YY,MMMM,MMM,MM,M,DDDD,DDD,DD,D,hhhh,hhh,hh,h,mm,m,ss,s,ampm,AMPM,dMod,th;
  YY = ((YYYY=this.getFullYear())+"").slice(-2);
  MM = (M=this.getMonth()+1)<10?('0'+M):M;
  MMM = (MMMM=["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"][M-1]).substring(0,3);
  DD = (D=this.getDate())<10?('0'+D):D;
  DDD = (DDDD=["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"][this.getDay()]).substring(0,3);
  th=(D>=10&&D<=20)?'th':((dMod=D%10)==1)?'st':(dMod==2)?'nd':(dMod==3)?'rd':'th';
  formatString = formatString.replace("#YYYY#",YYYY).replace("#YY#",YY).replace("#MMMM#",MMMM).replace("#MMM#",MMM).replace("#MM#",MM).replace("#M#",M).replace("#DDDD#",DDDD).replace("#DDD#",DDD).replace("#DD#",DD).replace("#D#",D).replace("#th#",th);
  h=(hhh=this.getHours());
  if (h==0) h=24;
  if (h>12) h-=12;
  hh = h<10?('0'+h):h;
  hhhh = hhh<10?('0'+hhh):hhh;
  AMPM=(ampm=hhh<12?'am':'pm').toUpperCase();
  mm=(m=this.getMinutes())<10?('0'+m):m;
  ss=(s=this.getSeconds())<10?('0'+s):s;
  return formatString.replace("#hhhh#",hhhh).replace("#hhh#",hhh).replace("#hh#",hh).replace("#h#",h).replace("#mm#",mm).replace("#m#",m).replace("#ss#",ss).replace("#s#",s).replace("#ampm#",ampm).replace("#AMPM#",AMPM);
};
```

Answer (score 63):

You can simply us the [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) library in order to convert the date to your desired format.

I've run couples of test and it works.

Below is a snippet illustrating how you can achieve that:

```
var d = new Date(1469433907836);

d.toLocaleString(); // expected output: "7/25/2016, 1:35:07 PM"

d.toLocaleDateString(); // expected output: "7/25/2016"

d.toDateString();  // expected output: "Mon Jul 25 2016"

d.toTimeString(); // expected output: "13:35:07 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

d.toLocaleTimeString(); // expected output: "1:35:07 PM"
```

Comment: Those examples don't require Datejs, they are part of JavaScript. But they work and totally satisfy the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Below is a snippet to enable you format the date to a desirable output:

```
var time = new Date();
var time = time.getTime();

var theyear = time.getFullYear();
var themonth = time.getMonth() + 1;
var thetoday = time.getDate();

document.write("The date is: ");
document.write(theyear + "/" + themonth + "/" + thetoday);
```

Comment: You do not need semi-colons in JavaScript. However, its best practice to use them. Sometimes, without them, the meaning of a statement can change (not in this case though). Some code reviewers zealously love them and fight for their presence. To keep things simple, its best to always use them.

Answer (score 18):

Try using this code:

```
var datetime = 1383066000000; // anything
var date = new Date(datetime);
var options = {
        year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric',
    };

var result = date.toLocaleDateString('en', options); // 10/29/2013
```

See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Answer (score 9):

Try using this code:

```
var milisegundos = parseInt(data.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""));
var newDate = new Date(milisegundos).toLocaleDateString("en-UE");
```

Enjoy it!

Answer (score 6):

so you need to pass that var time after getTime() into another new Date()
here is my example:

```
var time = new Date()
var time = time.getTime()
var newTime = new Date(time)
console.log(newTime)
//Wed Oct 20 2021 15:21:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

here output is my datetime standard format for you it will be in country format

if you want it in another format then you can apply another date function on var newTime
like

```
var newTime = new Date(time).toDateString()
console.log(newTime)
//Wed Oct 20 2021
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this one :

```
var time = new Date().toJSON();
```

Answer (score 3):

One line code.

```
var date = new Date(new Date().getTime());
```

or

```
var date = new Date(1584120305684);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/Date(1383066000000)/

function convertDate(data) {
    var getdate = parseInt(data.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""));
    var ConvDate= new Date(getdate);
    return ConvDate.getDate() + "/" + ConvDate.getMonth() + "/" + ConvDate.getFullYear();
}
```

Comment: Try to explain why this answer solve the problem please, avoid just posting the code.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the date as milliseconds date is `1526813885836`, so you can access the date as string with this sample code:

```
console.log(new Date(1526813885836).toString());
```

For clearness see below code:

```
const theTime = new Date(1526813885836);
console.log(theTime.toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

use datejs

```
new Date().toString('yyyy-MM-d-h-mm-ss');
```