# Javascript Convert Date To UTC

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to format a JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date)

I have a JSON that contains some dates that I need to be in a UTC format.

At present if I alert the dates out they are in the following format:

/Date(1329314400000)/

I am trying to loop round the JSON but am unsure on how to convert the above date format to UTC.

If anyone has any advice I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673527/converting-milliseconds-to-a-date-jquery-js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this out: [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date)

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
```