# How do I convert the "time" from the Meetup API to a recognizable format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, meetup

http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/2/event/

Here's the Meetup API's definition of time:

> Event start time in milliseconds since the epoch, or relative to the current time in the d/w/m format.

Here's the type of value I see returned in the JSON:

```
"time": 1382742000000,
```

Any advice about how to convert it into something recognizable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting milliseconds to a date (jQuery/JS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673527/converting-milliseconds-to-a-date-jquery-js)

Comment: var dt = new Date(1382742000000) this will give you date object & to display it use this dt.toString() this will gives you an output "Sat Oct 26 2013 04:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

Comment: If you are using python, datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ms/1000.0) works. I know this question is for javascript, but this is the first post to come up on google.

Comment: Just in case anyone using a different language needs to know: the "epoch" here is the same as the Unix epoch, named "01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct a date object like this

```
var date = new Date(milliseconds);
```

And then you could apply any format you want using [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) properties

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
// Convert milliseconds since since 00:00:00 UTC, Thursday, 1 January 1970 (the epoch in Unix speak)
var date = new Date(1382742000000);

// now get individual properties from the date object to construct a new format

// hours part from the timestamp
var hours = date.getHours();

// minutes part from the timestamp
var minutes = date.getMinutes();

// seconds part from the timestamp
var seconds = date.getSeconds();

// display time in our new format
var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
```

Comment: You don't need the `*1000`.  JavaScript uses milliseconds, which is what we already have.

Answer (score 1):

moment.js library can help very well

moment(1382742000000)
will give you object
and inside of it you can see:

Fri Oct 25 2013 19:00:00