# Unknown Date Fomat

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Not sure if this is the correct thread to post this type of question. I am calling a service which returns the date, but the format is quite weird. I couldn't figure out.

The format is : "/Date(1430953200000+0100)/"

and I want to convert this into dd month year format(ex 22 Feb 1991).

Any way to achieve this in javascript.

Comment: Maybe that is the value in ms! But I guess this should be fixed on the server side

Comment: What's weird in specific?

Comment: The number represents a date. `var d = new Date(1430953200000+0100)` returns Thu May 07 2015 08:30:00 GMT+0930 (Cen. Australia Standard Time)

Comment: That I know, but how can I convert into the required format

Comment: How do you normally convert a date in javascript? Have you checked the docs? Have you searched this site?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is the date in milliseconds.

I had the same problem a while ago and solved it using the following code.
However, I wanted the MMM/DD/YYYY format, so you'll have to change the string a bit.

```
function convertDate(date) {
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
              'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

return months[date.getUTCMonth()] + ' ' + date.getUTCDate() + ' ' + date.getUTCFullYear();
}

console.log(convertDate(new Date(1430953200000));
```

Comment: Right but you're ignoring time zone offset. It may be an issue if offset (from server) isn't always 1 hour.

Comment: He doesn't want to have a `hh:mm:ss format`, so it should be fine I guess? I also doubt that the location of his server will suddenly change timezones.

Comment: Offset is in hours so date may change. Server won't walk away to another country but we don't know how that date must be presented. For example, here on SO, server may return such date and each one of us will see date expressed in his own time zone (in this case you can't simply ignore it).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are legit and working answers downvoted?

Comment: @daZza, even if the time part is not needed, you can report a wrong date if the offset is, let's say 1 hour and the user accessed the site after 23:00 he could see the date for the next day. Timezone issues must never be underestimated. Moreover, if the client (javascript) code creates additional date objects in the user's browser to later submit them on the server (maybe via date-picker widget), those will use the client's timezone. One should know how to work these around.

Answer (score -1):

```
var time = new Date().getTime();
var date = new Date(time);
alert(date.toString()); // Wed Jan 12 2011 12:42:46 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

From:
[Converting milliseconds to a date (jQuery/JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673527/converting-milliseconds-to-a-date-jquery-js)

Comment: IMO if you post exact code from another answer (even with proper reference) then...it's easier to close **this** as duplicate...

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
mydate = new Date(1430953200000+0100)
```

then you can do whateveryou want with the js date format

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SLhQL/