# I have to convert this string (Wed, 2 Jul 2014 19:18:01 +0530) into javascript date object

Tags: javascript

I have the string like "Wed, 2 Jul 2014 19:18:01 +0530", and I want to convert this string into a javascript date object,
Please suggest me a best way to do this.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please do some research before posting here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple

```
var date = new Date("Wed, 2 Jul 2014 19:18:01 +0530");
```

Comment: +1 because I think that it's a working example and score of -1 is not right

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
 var time= Date.parse("Wed, 2 Jul 2014 19:18:01 +0530"); //number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC
 var date = new Date(time);
```

refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) for documentation about Date.parse,
 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673527/converting-milliseconds-to-a-date-jquery-js) for Converting milliseconds to a date.

also

```
var date = new Date("Wed, 2 Jul 2014 19:18:01 +0530");
```

should work