# javascript change timestamp value '1434460015' to 'y-m-d'

Tags: javascript

I know how to change date to readable format in php  like below

```
$jobpostdate = date("Y-m-d", '1434460015');
```

how can I do same thing with JavaScript If I have this UNIX timestamp value `1434460015` or any other UNIX timestamp value value like this , I have to do this within ajax success function, what can be the syntax?

Comment: what is `1434460015 `??

Comment: *"or any other value like this"* What exactly is "this"? A UNIX timestamp?

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673527/converting-milliseconds-to-a-date-jquery-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple use

```
 new Date(1434460015000) //If it's in second convert it into millisecond by *1000
```

For format it you need to do it in manual way

```js
    var today=new Date(1434460015000);
     var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        if(dd<10){
            dd='0'+dd
        } 
        if(mm<10){
            mm='0'+mm
        }
     
    var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
alert(today);
```

Comment: why we check this `if(dd<10)` here?

Comment: just to make it two digit :) so 9 turns to 09 :)

Answer (score 0):

.toUTCString might be able to help you.