# convert from milliseconds to date format in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a js time in milliseconds. How can I convert it to the format:

**Day Mon date yyyy UTC GMT e.g
Fri Feb 05 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)**

Thanks

Comment: We wont help you with code right of the bat. But after one google search i found an answer on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673527/converting-milliseconds-to-a-date-jquery-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var milliseconds = new Date().getTime(); //Get milliseconds
var date = new Date(milliseconds); // Create date from milliseconds
console.log(date.toString()); //Log: Fri Feb 05 2016 12:41:18 GMT+0200 (EET)

// Let's create futureDate, 5days after now ...
var millisecondsInDay = 8.64e+7; // Milliseconds per day
var futureDate = new Date(milliseconds + 5*millisecondsInDay);
console.log(futureDate.toString()); //Log: Wed Feb 10 2016 12:41:18 GMT+0200 (EET)
```

Comment: how about I add 5 days to new Date().getTime() and get the milliseconds and then reconvert it? Would it work?

Comment: Yes sure, i will update answer..

Answer (score 1):

Just use this, where timestamp is yours

```
new Date(timestamp).toString()
```