# Why is my Date object returning the current date?

Tags: javascript, date

I have my time since epoch stored as a number: 1444749469000. However, when I try to convert it to a Date object, using `Date(1444749469000)`, it just gives me the current date instead of the one it should be (around Tue Oct 13 2015).

---

```
> Date(1444749469000)
"Tue Apr 12 2016 09:28:30 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting milliseconds to a date (jQuery/JS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673527/converting-milliseconds-to-a-date-jquery-js)

Comment: @A.J. doesn't look like the OP checked that link to me.

Answer (score 3):

You need a `new` before the `Date` because `Date` is a constructor:

```js
var d = new Date(1444749469000)
alert(d);
```

Comment: By definition, constructors **are** functions. ;-) The difference is how they're called.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you call `Date` as a function, it will return a string of current date and ignore the given value. In order to retrieve the `Date` object, you must initialize the `Date` constructor with keyword `new`.

```
var now = Date(1444749469000);
var date = new Date(1444749469000);
console.log(typeof now); //string
console.log(typeof date); //object
```