# Transform this date format

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

this date format 1459468800000 corresponds to "April 2016".

Can anybody explain this to me?

What js-library can handle the transformation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting milliseconds to a date (jQuery/JS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673527/converting-milliseconds-to-a-date-jquery-js)

Comment: Open the console and type `new Date(1459468800000)` - it converts it without the need of a library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is [Epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)), the count of milliseconds from the 1970-01-01. First introduced with [UNIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).