# Is there a method to convert miliseconds to years,months,days,minutes,seconds in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compare 2 dates and represent the difference( converted to miliseconds) via years,months,days,minutes and seconds.I am new in JS,I looked up for a ready method to convert miliseconds to years,months,days, minutes, seconds but didn't find.Tell me please is there such method? If not how can I do that? Simply by dividing the difference  and using reminder?Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting milliseconds to a date (jQuery/JS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673527/converting-milliseconds-to-a-date-jquery-js)

Comment: I thibk you can just pass it to the Date object as argumebt, then get the time

Comment: The best you can do is be approximate, because the definition of a year/month is not static. There're leap years and months have different lengths.

Comment: Given the description, it's more likely a duplicate of [Difference between two dates in years, months, days in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732897/difference-between-two-dates-in-years-months-days-in-javascript)

Comment: You could just use maths? E.g. `x/100 = y` (seconds), `y/60 = m` (minutes), `m/60 = h` (hrs), `h/24 = d` (days) etc.. (maths is probably way off, but you get the picture)

Comment: depperm,I got the diference in miliseconds,now I need to covert the difference to y;m;d;m;s.For instance the user sets a Date , my program must show- from that date x years y months x minutes and etc have passed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without having a calendar and knowing the input dates, the best you can do is be approximate.

Here is a script that shows the time elapsed since midnight last night.

```js
var diff = Date.now() - Date.parse("July 13, 2016");

var seconds = Math.floor(diff / 1000),
    minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60),
    hours   = Math.floor(minutes / 60),
    days    = Math.floor(hours / 24),
    months  = Math.floor(days / 30),
    years   = Math.floor(days / 365);

seconds %= 60;
minutes %= 60;
hours %= 24;
days %= 30;
months %= 12;

console.log("Years:", years);
console.log("Months:", months);
console.log("Days:", days);
console.log("Hours:", hours);
console.log("Minutes:", minutes);
console.log("Seconds:", seconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt method to convert given millisecond to equivalent seconds, minutes, hours, days, months or years.

You will have to use math. Although you will only be able to convert accurately up to days. Months and years will vary as months are either 28, 29, 30 or 31 and there are leap years.

Consider having a look at http://momentjs.com/ before you write anything on your own, as you can do a lot more with this library like adding and subtracting days or hours etc

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution similar to other answers but with a different approach, I started from years instead of millis, I think is more accurate this way.

```js
    const date = new Date(startDate).getTime()
    const today = new Date().getTime()
    
    // 1000 millis => sec , 86400 sec => day , 365 day => year
    let years = (today - date) / (1000 * 86400 * 365)
    let months = (years - Math.floor(years)) * 12
    let days = (months - Math.floor(months)) * 30
    let hours = (days - Math.floor(days)) * 24
    let minutes = (hours - Math.floor(hours)) * 60
    let sec = (minutes - Math.floor(minutes)) * 60
    let milli = (sec - Math.floor(sec)) * 1000
    
    years = Math.floor(years)
    months = Math.floor(months)
    days = Math.floor(days)
    hours = Math.floor(hours)
    minutes = Math.floor(minutes)
    sec = Math.floor(sec)
    milli = Math.floor(milli)
```