# Javascript sum up time values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following values as Json.
14:49:09
00:16:46
00:00:05

I want to iterate through them while summing them up to come up with the final time of:

15:06:00 in Javascript

Comment: Show the JSON. What code have you tried so far?

Comment: is it a Json or a sheer array ?

Comment: switch to milliseconds, add up, go back to time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) You've described the problem. Make an attempt to solve it. If you run into a **specific** problem doing so, post your attempt and say what the problem you're running into is.

Comment: @kevinternet it is json

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks i will try that thanks

Answer (score 2):

At first, you need to loop the elements, then take those values from JSON and create [Date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) objects, [parse to milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js), add together and [go back to Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673527/converting-milliseconds-to-a-date-jquery-js).

```
var time_sum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var obj = new Date(json[i]);
    time_sum += obj.getTime();
}
var total_date = new Date(time_sum);
```