# How to convert "date(1494343074100)" that into formatted datetime in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am passing a date time from controller to view. In view i can get the date as **date(1494343074100)**. How can i convert the date into formatted datetime. please any one help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673527/converting-milliseconds-to-a-date-jquery-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting milliseconds to a date (jQuery/JS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673527/converting-milliseconds-to-a-date-jquery-js)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a way to convert to date.

```js
var time = 1494343074100;
var date = new Date(time);
console.log(date.toString());
```