# How to convert millisecond(1304921325178.3193) to 'yyyy-mm-dd' in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to convert `1304921325178.3193` to `yyyy-mm-dd` -> in javascript?

I use highchart and I would like to convert `data(xAxis[0]0)` to `yyyy-mm-dd`.

I tried to parse the millisecond using this function

```
function(valTime) {
 var date = new Date(valTime);
 var y = date.getFullYear();
 var m = date.getMonth() + 1;    
 var d = date.getDate();    
 m = (m < 10) ? '0' + m : m; 
 d = (d < 10) ? '0' + d : d;
 return [y, m, d].join('-');
}
```

However, there is a gap between actual date(2015-01-26) and selected date in the chart (2015-01-29).
[captured image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKLfm.png)
I guess if I calculate .3193, the date will be matched.

Is there any way to get the right date from the millisecond?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting milliseconds to a date (jQuery/JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673527/converting-milliseconds-to-a-date-jquery-js)

Comment: You can convert millisecond to date by `new Date(millisecond)`. But this is `Date`. You might want to see https://momentjs.com to display the Date in your preferred format.

Answer (score 5):

Your ms are actually pointing to 2011-05-09T06:08:45.178Z:

```js
var date = new Date(1304921325178.3193); // Date 2011-05-09T06:08:45.178Z
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    
console.log(`${year}-${month}-${day}`); // 2011-05-09
```