# What does my date time get converted into from ASP.Net MVC to Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datetime, datetime-format

In my html file I'm passing an array of objects with a date time to javascript like this

```
<script>
    var TimerEvents = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PendingTimerEvents));
</script>
```

my 'TimerEvents' has an EventTime property that when I read in Javascript looks like this

> "/Date(1521617700000)/"

and I want to get this value, whatever it is, into a Javascript Date() object.
like this

```
var countDownDate = new Date(date here).getTime();
```

What is that format, and how would I do this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to call an api endpoint, that returns properly encoded dates, instead of using the views model?

Comment: what's an API endpoint?

Comment: I could format the date time on the server before I pass it to the client! Maybe I should do that?

Comment: https://www.asp.net/web-api You can read it all here

Comment: ya I here ya about the API but that would be way more work for what I need here. I'm just doing a fetch and loading data into a page

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*ASP.NET MVC JsonResult Date Format*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format).

Answer (score 0):

the value you get is a milisecond representation of the date, I think the count starts at 1/1/1970.

Anyway here is a solution for formatting it:
[Converting milliseconds to a date (jQuery/JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673527/converting-milliseconds-to-a-date-jquery-javascript)

Comment: so basically I just pass in the number to the date function? Maybe I don't know how to use the immediate window in Visual Studio but I tried that and it returned undefined

Comment: Yes but what you are getting back is not a valid json result, it's a string, you'll have to first extract the miliseconds from it and pass it to a new Date object

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Model.PendingTimerEvents is a DateTime, you could just do:

```
 var TimerDate = new Date(@Model.PendingTimerEvents.Year, @Model.PendingTimerEvents.Month, @Model.PendingTimerEvents.Day, @Model.PendingTimerEvents.Hour, @Model.PendingTimerEvents.Minute, @Model.PendingTimerEvents.Second);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can extract the date with regex if you need to:

```
<script>
    var TimerEvents = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PendingTimerEvents)); //"/Date(1521617700000)/" 
    var dateString = TimerEvents.match(/\d+/)[0] // "1521617700000"
    var date = new Date(+dateString); //convert to number
    console.log(date); // Wed Mar 21 2018 08:35:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)
</script>
```