# How to format DateTime in JSON data returned from web API

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to `webAPI`. When i tried to return date-time in JSON format it returned as **/Date(1531378800000)/** .  Insted of **Thu Jul 12 2018 12:30:00**.

Could you please help me with this issue.
Thanks, In Advance. (Sorry for my Bad English).

**Update:** [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28939110/8375010) Solved my Problem.

Thanks to [codecaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266143/codecaster)

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster. But, i need to parse in WEB API itself not in script.

Comment: Read past the first answer.

Comment: Are you saying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28939110/8375010)

Comment: For example, but there are more answers like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the link given below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38567652/8376697

(i.e you can use Datejs library to get the date in your required format)