# How to read data in JavaScript from a Java server?

Tags: javascript, java, server, client

I'm running a simple server that show time, and when someone connects to it using telnet\putty he can see the time.

I need to write a code in JavaScript that reads the data from the server.
how do I do this ?

this is the server code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Calendar;




class ClientThread extends Thread {

   private final Socket _socket;

   public ClientThread( Socket socket ) {
      System.out.println( "New client" );
      _socket = socket;
      setDaemon( true );
      start();
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      try(
         final OutputStream outputFromServer = _socket.getOutputStream();
         final PrintWriter serverPrintOut = new PrintWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter( outputFromServer, "utf-8" ), true ))
      {
         serverPrintOut.println( "Welcome to time server" );
         for(;;) {
            final long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - MyServer.StartTime;
            serverPrintOut.println( elapsed );
            Thread.sleep( 1000L );
         }
      }
      catch( final InterruptedException ex) {/**/}
      catch( final IOException e ) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}

public class MyServer {

   static Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
   static long StartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();



   public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
      try( ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket( 9991 )) {
         for(;;) {
            new ClientThread( serverSocket.accept());
         }
      }
   }
}
```

this is what I have in JavaScript

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <%--<script type="text/javascript" src="jsocket.js"></script>--%>
    <%--<script type='text/javascript'>--%>
        <%--// Host we are connecting to--%>
        <%--var host = '10.0.0.82';--%>
        <%--// Port we are connecting on--%>
        <%--var port = 9991;--%>

        <%--var socket = new JSocket();--%>

        <%--// When the socket is added the to document--%>
        <%--socket.onReady = function(){--%>
            <%--socket.connect(host, port);--%>
        <%--}--%>

        <%--// Connection attempt finished--%>
        <%--socket.onConnect = function(success, msg){--%>
            <%--if(success){--%>
                <%--// Send something to the socket--%>
                <%--socket.write('Hello world');--%>
            <%--}else{--%>
                <%--alert('Connection to the server could not be estabilished: ' + msg);--%>
            <%--}--%>
        <%--}--%>
        <%--socket.onData = function(data){--%>
            <%--alert('Received from socket: '+data);--%>
        <%--}--%>

        <%--// Setup our socket in the div with the id="socket"--%>
        <%--socket.setup('mySocket');--%>
    <%--</script>--%>
    <script src="socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
//        var socket = io('http://10.0.0.82:9991');
//        socket.on('connect', function(){});
//        socket.on('event', function(data){});
//        socket.on('disconnect', function(){});


        var socket = io('10.0.0.82:9991');
        socket.on('news', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

but when I run the JavaScript code I get error "Invalid http resonse" 
which I understand why(the server is not http) - but how do I overcome this ?
what will be fast and easy - 
change the JavaScript or make the server http ?

- I do want to add that the final code will be handling 30 types of data (in the server) - all kind of sensor reading.

Comment: (please remember JavaScript is one word, this is to avoid confusion with Java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

According to [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673816/642706), here is the JavaScript for parsing a count of milliseconds since the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

```
var date = new Date( millisecondsSinceEpochReference );
```

## Additional suggestions

In addition to the JavaScript code, I can offer some major suggestions: Java Servlets, *java.time* classes, and ISO 8601 formats.

## Java Servlet

There is no need to re-invent a web server. [Java Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) technology was invented to make this kind of work very simple.

Write a simple servlet app that returns your desired string. Takes just a few lines of code.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet ( "/now" )
public class NowServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet ( HttpServletRequest req , HttpServletResponse res )
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        res.setContentType( "text/plain" );
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

        Instant instant = Instant.now();
        String output = instant.toString();

        out.println( output );
    }
}
```

Then run your servlet on any Servlet-compliant server (a [web container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container)) such as [Apache Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) or [Eclipse Jetty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_(web_server)).

If you want to, you could get fancy by making a [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) web service.

## java.time

Your Java backend is using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

If you insist on tracking a moment as a count from an [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)), here is code to get a count of [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) since [1970-01-01T00:00Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

```
Instant.now().toEpochMilli()
```

But I suggest you exchange text rather than this mere integer. Read on.

## ISO 8601

When exchanging date-time values as text, use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatting. These formats are practical and useful, designed to avoid ambiguity, and are easy to parse by machine as well as easy to read by humans across cultures.

The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

For a value in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class.

```
String output = Instant.now().toString() ;
```

> 2018-11-13T02:16:19.422836Z

You can parse such a string back into an object.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2018-11-13T02:16:19.422836Z" ) ;
```

If your destination is restricted to milliseconds instead of *java.time* resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), truncate.

```
String output = 
    Instant
    .now()
    .truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MILLIS )
    .toString() 
;
```

> 2018-11-13T02:18:05.333Z

You *may* want to exchange the value as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone)). But generally speaking, the best practice is to exchange moments in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

For a time zone, use the [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class. The `toString` method on this class wisely extends the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```
String output = 
    ZonedDateTime                          // Represent a moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
    .now(                                  // Capture the current moment.
        ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )    // Always specify proper zone name in `Continent/Region` format, never 2-4 letter pseudo-zones such as PST, EST, CEST, or IST.
    )                                      // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
    .toString()                            // Generates text in ISO 8601 format extended to append the name of zone in square brackets.
```

> 2018-11-12T21:27:54.595139-05:00[America/Montreal]

You can parse such a string back into an object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( "2018-11-12T21:27:54.595139-05:00[America/Montreal]" ) ;
```

If need be, truncate as seen above.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).