# milliseconds to date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, format

I'm using React JS to create an App.
During the process, I've created a component "Card Component" that I'm calling on the App.js.
The mission of that component is to print details in a card.
So far, everything is working fine, except the date!
As you can see on the prints that I have below... I've tried a few different approaches, but I'm stuck! I can't think of anything else and my knowledge is still short! 
I've managed to console.log the third one with a string that is the accurate date that I need, however, I'm not being able to transform it to a date&time format!

**Code:**

[image]

**Console.log**

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673527/converting-milliseconds-to-a-date-jquery-javascript asked and answered

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting milliseconds to a date (jQuery/JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673527/converting-milliseconds-to-a-date-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Change your `<h4>` to include

```
<h4>{console.log("third:",new Date(new Date().getTime(`${props.country.updated}``)).toString())}</h4>
```

You can also use `customFormat` for your use-case

```
<h4>{console.log("third:",new Date().customFormat("#DD#/#MM#/#YYYY#"))}</h4>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You pointed me on the correct direction, however, with a slight difference.
{console.log(new Date(new Date(props.country.updated).toString()))}

With that I'm being able to print to the console.log the time that is stored on "updated".

Now a new problem happens! 

Using: <h4>{new Date(new Date(props.country.updated).toString())}</h4>

I'm getting an error: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Tue Apr 07 2020 15:47:06 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Any idea?