# what is datetype is this in highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts

Sort of a stupid question but i can't fiquire out what datetype is this and how to manipulate it.

```
var ranges = [
            [1246406400000, 3, 2],
            [1246492800000, 2.9, 1.8],

            [1246665600000, 2.5, 1.6],
            [1246752000000, 2, 1]

        ],
        averages = [
            [1246406400000, 2.4],
            [1246492800000, 2.3],

            [1246665600000, 1.9],
            [1246752000000, 1.6]

        ];
```

in this what date format is 1246406400000.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what type of chart you try to render. Most of charts required data in this format:

```
[x, y]
```

or

```
[x, y, z]
```

Where x could be a number in milliseconds - like in the example which you shared - 1246406400000. You can use some online calculators to check what data it is, like this one https://currentmillis.com/ or by using JS, like it is explained here: [Converting milliseconds to a date (jQuery/JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673527/converting-milliseconds-to-a-date-jquery-javascript)